# How to store ios application state in cordova app

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using cordova-2.1.0 and jqueryMobile for ios app.I have added phone call feature inside the app.But when I end the phone call application gets restart because I have set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in appName.plist and can't remove that key because I want to exit the app when user press the home button.I think the alternative for resume app after phone call ends is to store the app state before call and restore the app at that state after call end.I am using a simple plugin for dialing number.Please give give me suggestions.

Comment: please reply I stuck here since last two days :(

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you need, BUT you might want to look at

1. [SQLite storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)
2. [HTML5 offline storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

I don't know if there is anything that will "serialize" your entire app and let you store that (as JSON/XML/binary) - IF that is what you are after....or if that is even possible.